# Cannot resolve symbol setOutputSoapObject

Tags: java, android, web-services

I am trying to call my webservice in my android application.

Following is the piece of code I am using -

```
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);        
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = 
        new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11); 

    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    HttpTransportSE myHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
```

But, setOutputSoapObject is underlined as red and saying cannot resolve symbol setOutputSoapObject.

Anyone has any ideas about this? I have made sure everything is imported.

Same problem with the following line-
androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

Says, call is not available. What can be the issue?

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

This was a silly mistake but for a newbie in Android App Dev it was something.

The code was placed outside the method and hence was showing error.

Fixed.